# Drupal : Want to capsule/cover the file field's URL

Tags: drupal

Short question ,

I have added a **file field** from **content types** ( I will accept video files : mp4 dat mpgeg)
I want to capsule it with window media player plugin

like this :

<-------------------------------------------code----------------------
url=filefield's url* (example : sample.mp4)

---------------------------------------------code---------------------->

**Can i create one with View Module?**

I did try with **header**[<-------------------------------------------code---------------------- ]

*output url of the file*

**footer** 
 [---------------------------------------------code----------------------> ]

It works , but the problem is we also have to display , other informaions also. Header - Footer things is not the best solution. Help!

Using
1. Durpal 7

Comment: There is a working module for Drupal 6 to solove issue. http://drupal.org/project/video   But i have to use Drupal 7 due to project nature.

Comment: Solved!

It was my firefox browser, dumping cache.
I restalled "video" module and try with new machine and work.
Now I set some file extensions to play with window media player plugin.
Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: if you found a solution, please post it as an answer and mark it accepted (after time required time as passed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was my firefox browser, dumping cache. I restalled "video" module and try with new machine and work. Now I set some file extensions to play with window media player plugin. Thanks everyone for your answers.